# Local files not displaying, apache server

Tags: html, apache, embed

I have these two lines in my html file:

```
 <p><img src="file:///var/www/html/foldername/image.gif"/>
 <p><audio src="file:///var/www/html/foldername/audiofile.mp3" controls><p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p></audio><p>
```

The files are within the directory of the web page, file permissions are root ownership, read only.

They are not displaying, how do i get them to show? I have only been toying around with this for a few days so my experience is very limited, i could well have done something blatantly wrong while configuring the server.

OS: Debian-Stable Apache: 2.2.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test this 
`<img src="image.gif"/>` 
or width apache root 
`<img src="/foldername/image.gif"/>`

Comment: The first one works, the second behaved the same as with the reply from annam priyatam. Thank You! One more thing, any idea how to get the audio to 'autoplay'?

Comment: just with <audio controls autoplay>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not give

```
file:///var/www/html....
```

Once try

```
<img src="folder/yourimage.gif">
```

Comment: Assuming 'folder' is the directory of the html file and image, this is not working. I get the text i set to say the audio failed to load and i get a little image indicating there should be an image, but the giff has also not loaded (this latter part is progress at least). Same in both firefox and chrome, with the exception chromium shows the audio player as well as the text. The answer from toto21 however has resolved the issue. Thank you for the help though.